# ¿Cómo conseguir modal remoto (ajax) con bootstrap 4?

Tags: ajax, bootstrap-4, modal

Tengo este código:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="es">
        <head>
            <meta charset="UTF-8">
            <title>Modal sin ajax</title>
            <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0">
            <link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.2.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-GJzZqFGwb1QTTN6wy59ffF1BuGJpLSa9DkKMp0DgiMDm4iYMj70gZWKYbI706tWS" crossorigin="anonymous">   
        </head>

        <body>
            <div class="container">
                <h2>Basic Modal Example</h2>

                <!-- Iniciar modal -->
                <a data-toggle="modal" href="#myModal">
                    <img class="img-fluid" src="imagen.png" alt="" style="width:20%">
                </a>

                <!-- Modal -->
                <div class="modal fade" id="myModal" role="dialog">
                    <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg">

                        <!-- Modal content-->
                        <div class="modal-content">
                            <div class="modal-header">
                                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
                                <h4 class="modal-title">Modal Header</h4>
                            </div>
                            <div class="modal-body">
                                <img class="img-fluid img-responsive" src="imagen.png" alt="">
                            </div>
                            <div class="modal-footer">
                                <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <!-- Close modal content-->

                    </div>
                </div>
                <!-- Close modal -->

            </div>
            <!-- Close container -->

            <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.js" integrity="sha256-2Kok7MbOyxpgUVvAk/HJ2jigOSYS2auK4Pfzbm7uH60=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script> 
            <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.2.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-B0UglyR+jN6CkvvICOB2joaf5I4l3gm9GU6Hc1og6Ls7i6U/mkkaduKaBhlAXv9k" crossorigin="anonymous"></script> 
            <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.2.1/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-zDnhMsjVZfS3hiP7oCBRmfjkQC4fzxVxFhBx8Hkz2aZX8gEvA/jsP3eXRCvzTofP" crossorigin="anonymous"></script> 
            <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.3/umd/popper.min.js"></script>    
        </body>
</html>
```

hasta acá no hay problemas, es un simple modal con ajax...
...quise llamar a este modal de forma remota con ajax utlizando la función glob de php para ubicar una imagen en un directorio:

index.php

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="es">
        <head>
            <meta charset="UTF-8">
            <title>Modal sin ajax</title>
            <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0">
            <link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.2.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-GJzZqFGwb1QTTN6wy59ffF1BuGJpLSa9DkKMp0DgiMDm4iYMj70gZWKYbI706tWS" crossorigin="anonymous">  
            <script type="text/javascript" src="js/modalJs.js"></script>
        </head>

        <body>
            <div class="container">
                <h2>Basic Modal Example</h2>

                <!-- Iniciar modal modal -->
                <a href="imagen.php"  class="modalImagen" data-toggle="modal" data-var="imagenes/imagen/">
                    <img class="img-fluid" src="imagen.png" alt="" style="width:20%">
                </a>

                <!-- Modal -->
                <div class="modal fade" id="myModal" role="dialog">
                    <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg">

                        <!-- Modal content-->
                        <div class="modal-content">
                            <div class="modal-header">
                                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
                                <h4 class="modal-title">Modal Header</h4>
                            </div>
                            <div class="modal-body">
                                <img class="imagenModal img-fluid img-responsive" src="" alt="">
                            </div>
                            <div class="modal-footer">
                                <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <!-- Close modal content-->

                    </div>
                </div>
                <!-- Close modal -->

            </div>
            <!-- Close container -->

            <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.js" integrity="sha256-2Kok7MbOyxpgUVvAk/HJ2jigOSYS2auK4Pfzbm7uH60=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script> 
            <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.2.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-B0UglyR+jN6CkvvICOB2joaf5I4l3gm9GU6Hc1og6Ls7i6U/mkkaduKaBhlAXv9k" crossorigin="anonymous"></script> 
            <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.2.1/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-zDnhMsjVZfS3hiP7oCBRmfjkQC4fzxVxFhBx8Hkz2aZX8gEvA/jsP3eXRCvzTofP" crossorigin="anonymous"></script> 
            <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.3/umd/popper.min.js"></script>    
        </body>
</html>
```

imagen.php

```
<?php
header('Content-Type: application/json');
$directorio = $_POST['var'];
echo json_encode (glob($directorio. '*.{png,mp4}', GLOB_BRACE));
?>
```

modalJs.js

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.modalImagen').click(function (event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        var data = this.dataset;

        $.ajax({
            url: "imagen.php",
            data: data,
            type: "POST",
            dataType: "json",
            success: function(data) {
                $('#myModal').addClass("show");
                var imgs = data.map(function(img) {
                    var html = "";
                    var fileExtension = img.substring(img.lastIndexOf('.'));
                    if (fileExtension == ".png") {
                        return html = '<img src="'+img+'"></img>';
                        $('.imagenModal').html(html);
                    }
                });
            } 
        });
    });
});
```

...pero el código no funciona. Alguien me podría ayudar?

Comment: Añade los errores que te muestra.

Comment: la página se queda bloqueada y la consola me muestra: `unreachable code after return statement` y `ReferenceError: $ is not defined`